# Getting the name of the cmake build directory excluding the full path

Tags: cmake

I am using CMake 3.23 and the build directory is `C:\Dev\MyProject\LibA\cmake-build-debug-vs`. `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` provide the full path to the build directory. Is there any way to only get `cmake-build-debug-vs`?

Does CMake have a dedicated variable for only the name of the build directory? I tried several built-in variables and they all return the full path.

Comment: As far as I know, CMake doesn't have a dedicated variable to contain relative paths in the build tree. If you want relative paths, then you could compute them using [file(RELATIVE_PATH)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#relative-path) command. Note, that `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` may differ from `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` more than by a single directory. E.g. a `CMakeLists.txt` included via `add_subdirectory()` call may call `add_subdirectory()` by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the name of the latest path component (filename or directory; depending on what is the last component) then you could use CMake's relative new [path features](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_path.html#get-parent-path).

This will extract `cmake-build-debug-vs` and store it into the variable `MY_BUILD_PATH_NAME`.

```
cmake_path (GET CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR PARENT_PATH MY_BUILD_PATH_NAME)
message (STATUS "MY_BUILD_PATH_NAME = \"${MY_BUILD_PATH_NAME}\"")
```

If you what to compute a relative path from your path to another path then you have to use the [file(RELATIVE_PATH)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#relative-path) API as already mentioned in the comments.

```
file (RELATIVE_PATH MY_BUILD_PATH_NAME "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../")
message (STATUS "MY_BUILD_PATH_NAME = \"${MY_BUILD_PATH_NAME}\"")
```

This will compute `../` and store it into the variable `MY_BUILD_PATH_NAME`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`get_filename_component` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_filename_component.html) can be used to extract parts of file names

```
get_filename_component(DIR_NAME_NOPATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} NAME)
message("Binary dir name: '${DIR_NAME_NOPATH}'")
```